# Vertx. From test having access to spring beans that are loaded with the verticle itself

Tags: java, spring, vert.x

I want initialize a verticle instance on deploy with spring context (all is annotations based with @Configurations etc.) and then be able to test it in integration tests,

My verticle:

```
public class MyServiceVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    final VerticleStringContextLoader verticleStringContextLoader = new VerticleStringContextLoader(
        "com.my.config",
        MyConfig.class
    );

    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {

        verticleStringContextLoader.connectWithVertx(vertx);

        verticleStringContextLoader.onStart(startFuture);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        verticleStringContextLoader.onStop();
    }

}
```

In the `VerticleStringContextLoader` I load spring beans that are loaded with verticle itself.

Like this:

```
            sharedContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
            sharedContext.register(VertxConfig.class);
            ...
            sharedContext.scan(componentScanPackages);
            sharedContext.refresh();
```

In tests,
 I would like to control spring context so that I could be able to have access to to those beans that are loaded.

In the integration test:
 when I deploy my verticle:

```
 @RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class) 
 ....

 vertx.deployVerticle(
                    MyServiceVerticle.class.getName(),
                    deploymentOptions,
                    testContext.asyncAssertSuccess( id -> {
                        ...
                    })
                );
```

The question is.. I guess I just shortcut like that:

**How from the test that deployes a verticle and initializes the spring I could have access/references to Loaded Spring beans** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh.. I guess I can do it in 3.5 version of vert.x (I use 3.4.2) -

http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html#deployVerticle-io.vertx.core.Verticle-io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions-

there is a proper method for it when deploy.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples/spring-verticle-factory. The Spring Verticle factory is a better solution as it allows to deploy multiple instances of the verticle if needed.